# regdno = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); data not inserted

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Data is not being inserted into SQL Server using a stored procedure.

Insert code in ASP.NET / C#:

```
private void insert()
{
    int regdno = 0;

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_bmsstudent"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                string strFilename = uploadImage(photos);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sphoto", strFilename.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admyear", ddlyear1.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addedddt", lbl_date.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admno", adm_no.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofadm", txt_dtadm.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname", txt_sname.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@preclass", ddlClass.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@presec", ddlsec.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@preroll", txt_roll.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priclass", txtpriclass.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prisec", ddlprisec.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priroll", txt_priroll.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sgender", rdo_gender.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sreligion", sreli.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", ddldate.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@smonth", dmonth.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@syear", ddlyear.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caste", chk_caste.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aadharno", txt_aadhar.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bg", txt_bg.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bplstatus", bpl_status.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bplno", bpl_no.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@svill", ddl_vill.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spost", txt_postname.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sps", txt_ps.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sblock", txt_block.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdist", txt_dist.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sstate", txt_state.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spincode", txt_pincode.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@snationality", txt_nation.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txt_fname.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fmob", txt_mobno.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foccu", txt_occu.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fqly", txt_qly.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@faincome", txt_income.Text.Trim());

                string strFilename2 = uploadImage2(photos2);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fphoto", strFilename2.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", txt_mother.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mmob", txt_mmobile.Text.Trim());

                string strFilename3 = uploadImage3(photos3);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mphoto", strFilename3.Trim());

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gname", txt_guar.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gmob", txt_gmob.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@relative", rdorelative.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@relation1", ddl_relation1.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rname1", txt_rname1.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rclass1", txt_rc1.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rsec1", txt_rsec1.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rroll1", txt_rroll1.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@relation2", ddl_relation2.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rname2", txt_rname2.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rclass2", txt_rc2.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rsec2", txt_rsec2.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rroll2", txt_rroll2.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@relation3", ddl_relation3.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rclass3", txt_rc3.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rsec3", txt_rsec3.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rroll3", txt_rroll3.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bankname", ddl_bank.SelectedValue.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bbranch", txt_branch.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bifsc", txt_ifsc.Text.Trim());

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@baccount", txt_baccount.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agree", declarationchk.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@other1", other1.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@other2", other2.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@other3", other3.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@other4", other4.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@other5", other5.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@other6", other6.Text.Trim());

                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();

                regdno = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                con.Close();
            }
        }

        string message = string.Empty;

        switch (regdno)
            {
                case -1:
                    message = "Student already exists.\\nEntered Students  roll no. already been used. Please Enter a different roll no..";
                    break;
                case -2:
                    message = "Supplied Account No. has already been used.";
                    break;
                default:
                    message = "Registration successful.  \\nYour Regd. no: " + regdno.ToString();
                    break;
            }
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);

            lblmsg.Text = regdno.ToString();
            string queryString = "http://example.org/admin/studentdetailspopup.aspx?userid=" + lblmsg.Text.Trim();

            string newWin = "window.open('" + queryString + "');";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pop", newWin, true);
        }

    }
    #endregion
```

Stored procedure :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_bmsstudent]  
    @admyear NVARCHAR(50),
    @addedddt DATE,
    @admno NVARCHAR(50),
    @dateofadm DATE,
    @sname NVARCHAR(100),
    @preclass NVARCHAR(50),
    @presec NVARCHAR(50),
    @preroll NVARCHAR(50),
    @priclass NVARCHAR(50),
    @prisec NVARCHAR(50),
    @priroll NVARCHAR(50),
    @sgender VARCHAR(50),
    @sreligion VARCHAR(50),
    @sdate NVARCHAR(50),
    @smonth NVARCHAR(50),
    @syear NVARCHAR(50),
    @caste VARCHAR(50),
    @sphoto NVARCHAR(50),
    @aadharno NVARCHAR(50),
    @bg NVARCHAR(50),
    @bplstatus NVARCHAR(50),
    @bplno NVARCHAR(50),
    @svill VARCHAR(500),
    @spost VARCHAR(50),
    @sps VARCHAR(50),
    @sblock VARCHAR(50),
    @sdist VARCHAR(50),
    @sstate VARCHAR(50),
    @spincode VARCHAR(50),
    @snationality VARCHAR(50),
    @fname VARCHAR(250),
    @fmob VARCHAR(50),
    @foccu VARCHAR(50),
    @fqly VARCHAR(50),
    @faincome VARCHAR(50),
    @fphoto VARCHAR(50),
    @mname VARCHAR(50),
    @mmob VARCHAR(50),
    @mphoto VARCHAR(50),
    @gname VARCHAR(50),
    @gmob VARCHAR(50),
    @relative VARCHAR(50),
    @relation1 VARCHAR(50),
    @rname1 VARCHAR(50),
    @rclass1 VARCHAR(50),
    @rsec1 VARCHAR(50),
    @rroll1 VARCHAR(50),
    @relation2 VARCHAR(50),
    @rname2 VARCHAR(50),
    @rclass2 VARCHAR(50),
    @rsec2 VARCHAR(50),
    @rroll2 VARCHAR(50),
    @relation3 VARCHAR(50),
    @rclass3 VARCHAR(50),
    @rsec3 VARCHAR(50),
    @rroll3 VARCHAR(50),
    @bankname VARCHAR(500),
    @bbranch NVARCHAR(500),
    @bifsc NVARCHAR(50),
    @baccount NVARCHAR(50),
    @agree VARCHAR(50),
    @other1 NVARCHAR(500),
    @other2 NVARCHAR(500),
    @other3 NVARCHAR(500),
    @other4 NVARCHAR(500),
    @other5 NVARCHAR(500),
    @other6 NVARCHAR(500)

    --@TaskParam int,  
    -- @Del int, 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT slno FROM fbmssms.bmsstudents WHERE preroll = @preroll)
    BEGIN
        SELECT -1 -- Username exists.
    END
    ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT slno FROM fbmssms.bmsstudents WHERE baccount = @baccount)
    BEGIN
        SELECT -2 -- Email exists.
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [fbmssms.bmsstudents]([admyear], [nvarchar], [addedddt], [admno], [dateofadm], [sname],
                                          [preclass], [presec], [preroll], [priclass], [prisec], [priroll],
                                          [sgender], [sreligion], [sdate], [smonth], [syear], [caste],
                                          [sphoto], [aadharno], [bg], [bplstatus], [bplno], [svill],
                                          [spost], [sps], [sblock], [sdist], [sstate], [spincode], [snationality],
                                          [fname], [fmob], [foccu], [fqly], [faincome], [fphoto], [mname],
                                          [mmob], [mphoto], [gname], [gmob], [relative], [relation1],
                                          [rname1], [rclass1], [rsec1], [rroll1], [relation2], [rname2], [rclass2],
                                          [rsec2], [rroll2], [relation3], [rclass3], [rsec3], [rroll3],
                                          [bankname], [bbranch], [bifsc], [baccount], [agree], 
                                          [other1], [other2], [other3], [other4], [other5], [other6])  
        VALUES (@admyear, @addedddt, @admno, @dateofadm, @sname,
                @preclass, @presec, @preroll, @priclass, @prisec, @priroll,
                @sgender, @sreligion, @sdate, @smonth, @syear, @caste,
                @sphoto, @aadharno, @bg, @bplstatus, @bplno, @svill,
                @spost, @sps, @sblock, @sdist, @sstate, @spincode, @snationality,
                @fname, @fmob, @foccu, @fqly, @faincome, @fphoto, @mname,
                @mmob, @mphoto, @gname, @gmob, @relative, @relation1,
                @rname1, @rclass1, @rsec1, @rroll1, @relation2, @rname2, @rclass2,
                @rsec2, @rroll2, @relation3, @rclass3, @rsec3, @rroll3,
                @bankname, @bbranch, @bifsc, @baccount, @agree,
                @other1, @other2, @other3, @other4, @other5, @other6)

        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()            
     END
END
```

Error....................

> Invalid object name 'fbmssms.bmsstudents'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'fbmssms.bmsstudents'.
>   Source Error:
>   Line 436:      cmd.Connection = con;
>   Line 437:      con.Open();
>   Line 438:      regdno = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
>   Line 439:      con.Close();
>   Line 440:  }

Connection was there. Even my same coding is running in another page in same style. Here I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: It is _[fbmssms].[bmsstudents]_ or _fbmssms.bmsstudents_

Comment: What database are you connected to? Is this `fbmssms` your schema? Just because your code is running in another page, same style, doesn't mean it's going to work the same. The invalid object error would suggest you are connected to the wrong db.

Answer (score 3):

`INSERT INTO [fbmssms.bmsstudents]` ... *Invalid object name 'fbmssms.bmsstudents'.*

There are a few possibilities here. As written, the `INSERT` statement is pointing to a table named `[fbmssms.bmsstudents]` in whatever database the connection object points to.

If you actually mean table `bmsstudents` in schema `fbmssms`, use  `[fbmssms].[bmsstudents]`.

If you mean table `bmsstudents` in the default schema in database `fbmssms`, use `[fbmssms]..[bmsstudents]` or `[fbmssms].[dbo].[bmsstudents]` (assumes that `dbo` is the default schema for the database).

If you mean the table named `[fbmssms.bmsstudents]`, you are probably connected to an incorrect database. Add the database name and schema to the table name, e.g. `[MyDatabase].[dbo].[fbmssms.bmsstudents]`.

Comment: thanks.. it helped [fbmssms].[bmsstudents]